# Save, Delete e Get em AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crud

Estou fazendo um falso "CRUD" em AngularJS e estou com problemas na funções save, delete e get. Apenas a função query() funcionou. Podem me ajudar, por gentileza? Vi que o motivo é algo relacionado a array, já alterei a função save para considerar array, mas isso não funcionou. E com o get não consigo pegar o elemento único que quero.

app.js

`var app = angular.module('app',['ngResource']);`

```
app.controller("lojaCtrl", function($scope, $resource){

    var Produto = $resource("/loja/produtos/", {
        "save:": {method: 'POST', isArray:true}
    }); 

    $scope.produto = {};
    $scope.produtos = [];

    $scope.getProdutoById = function(){
        Produto.get({Id:$scope.codigo}, function(data) { //função get
            $scope.produto = data;              
        });
    }

    $scope.getProdutos = function(){
        Produto.query(function(data) { //função query
            $scope.produtos = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.selectProduct = function(produto)
    {
        $scope.produto = produto;   
    }

    $scope.saveProduto = function(){
        $scope.products = Produto.query();
        new Produto().$save(function(data) {
            $scope.products.push(data);
        });
    }

    $scope.deleteProduto = function(){
        Produto.delete({Id:$scope.codigo}, function(data) { //função get
        });
    }

});
```

Index.php



`header('Content-Type: application/json');

$banco = "produtos";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$usuario,$senha); mysql_select_db($banco) or die( "Não foi possível conectar ao banco MySQL");      

$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_produtos";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $products[] = (object)array(
    'id' =>$row['id'], 
    'name' =>$row['nome']
    );
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO t_produtos(nome) VALUES('inserir')";

echo json_encode($products);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O default do service $resource do angular é o REST. Portanto você deve declarar especificamente os métodos HTTP que usa se não está utilizando o padrão REST.
Métodos default do $resource descritps na [API do Angular:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Se você mandar um DELETE para um método que aceita apenas POST, provavelmente te retornará "method not allowed".
Outro ponto importante é enviar dados no formato JSON. Coverta seu array javascript dessa forma:

```
var arrJson = JSON.stringfy(meuArray);
```

A variável arrJson vai conter o json em formato de string. E como você está mandando o content-type como application/json provavelmente vai dar certo :)

Comment: desculpe a demora e muito obrigado :D

Comment: Tranquilo! Vlw :D